# iTerm2 disable tab suggestion dropdown

Tags: autocomplete, dropdown, autosuggest, iterm2

I remember being able to just press Tab and toggle through suggestions in iTerm2.

For example "cd" enter, then "u", then press tab and go through the folders:

users, utilities, ux, etc.

Instead now Tab opens a dropdown that i have to interact with hampering productivity.

Does anyone know how to get the old functionality back, or if it's a plugin or a setting that's the culprit?